# mongodb shell not responding after running update query with $set

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongo-java-driver

I am writing a query to find and update an array in a document, but mongo shell is not responding after running the update query using `$set`. The array in the document is not updated, and also no response is shown for any of the commands ran after update.

My update query looks as below,

```js
db.TestFlowSteps.update(
  {"testFlowId":"23","testRunDetail.testRunDetailId":"1"},
  {$set: {'testRunDetail.$.applicationId':'5'}})
)
```

This is an example document:

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("58c92abd43df987ae87e1c79"),
   "testFlowId":"23",
   "testRunDetail":[

      {
         "testRunDetailId":"1",
         "testRunId":"23",
         "applicationName":"APP",
         "applicationId":"41",
         "testCaseId":"818",
         "testCaseName":"Test123",
         "browserMode":"YES",
         "index":1,
         "edit":false
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add the sample document from your collection ?

Comment: @Veeram added a sample document

Comment: You are missing closing parenthesis for set document. Try `db.TestFlowSteps.update(   {"testFlowId":"23","testRunDetail.testRunDetailId":"1"},   {$set: {'testRunDetail.$.applicationId':'5'} } )`

Comment: @Veeram, Thanks
But its a type 'o' mistake from my side. mongo shell notifies this kind of syntax errors. 
No error has been displayed after running the query.

Comment: How many entries does your collection have? Are the fields you query for indexed? What is the output of `.explain`. Please edit your question accordingly.